# How to store google auth and data copied from cloud storage across sessions in Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I recently started using Google Colab and found that I need to reauth and recopy my data which is stored on Google Cloud Storage every time I start a new session. 
Given that I'm using all Google services, is there a way to ensure that my settings are maintained in the environment?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to persist local files on the VM across sessions. You'll want to store persistent data externally in something like Drive, GCS, or your local filesystem.

Some recipes are available in the [I/O example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb).

Comment: Hmmm I'm wondering why you are calling data stored externally as persistent data? I already store my data on GCS and it is "persistent" on GCS as it should be but not on my Colab notebook. Am I right in inferring that from a colab notebook's perspective, there is no persistent data facility?